# Arduino отправка данных на сервер TCP

Tags: администрирование, tcp, arduino, передача-данных, сеть

Здравсвуйте, помогите пожалуйста, лазил лазил по интернету но так и не смог найти вразумительного ответа, гугл мне упорно пытается пропихнуть отправку данных GET запросами.

Суть: ардуинка должна отправить данные на сервер по GPRS. Как подключиться к компьютеру и отправить ему байты я уже разобрался.

Вопрос: Чем ловить их на компе, чтоб потом передать в базу SQL? Принципиально НЕ слать данные GET или POST. Какие тонкости при этом следует учесть(подтверждение приема? контрольную сумму данных? проверка целлостности данных? и т.п.). Таких ардуинок будет несколько, данные примерно раз в 30с, сможет ли комп принимать их одновременно или если активна передача с одной ардуиной то вторая поперхнется, как этого избежать?

Comment: На стороне сервера создаёте консольное приложение для прослушки указанного вами порта и обрабатываете всё что приходит на него.

Comment: @Rootware спасибо, как быть с попыткой двух ардуин отправить данные?

Comment: Не проблема, хоть тысяча одновременно. С такими скоростями базу они явно не перегрузят.

Comment: @Сергей просто добавьте к данными ID устройства. Этим вы будете определять кто и что прислал.

Comment: И авторизацию, чтобы вам кто попало не присылал что захочется.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev я имел ввиду, что пока 1 ардуина передаёт данные она занимает порт, если вторая в этот момент попытается передать, что произойдет?

Comment: Да ничего страшного не произойдёт, будут передавать одновременно. Если сервер будете писать самостоятельно с нуля на Си, к этому нужно принять некоторые явные меры, если же воспользуетесь каким-либо полуготовым решением, то там это сразу встроено.

Comment: а в сторону OPC сервера не смотрели?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На стороне сервера надо ловить программой-сервером, навскидку для реализации не-HTTP протокола могу предложить к рассмотрению следующие варианты из того, что попроще-побыстрее.

1. [Tornado (Python)](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/tcpserver.html)
2. [Net::Server (Perl)](https://habr.com/post/120170/)
3. Сервис для inetd — пишется на чём угодно и работает с stdin/stdout; inetd сам запустит, сам привяжет сокет, сам корректно очистит по завершении.

Что касается проверки целостности данных и контрольных сумм — вообще-то TCP решает эти вопросы, но так как у вас с одной стороны микроконтроллер, то и реализация TCP может оказаться несколько самобытной :)

Предусмотрите авторизацию клиентов на сервере и (особенно вслучае с работой через inetd) завершение соединения по таймауту, т.к. inetd запускает новый процесс-сервер на каждое входящее соединение, что при большом количестве незакрытых соединений может привести к исчерпанию памяти компьютера-сервера.

Ну и всякое такое: проверяйте длину считываемых от клиента строк; делайте минимальный контроль получаемых данных, чтобы при утечке данных авторизации вам хотя бы не подсунули SQL injection; и проч. стандартные рекомендации по безопасности.

Comment: спасибо попробую разобраться с торнадо

Comment: а можете пожалуйста, обрисовать как должна выглядеть авторизация через tcp логически?

Comment: @Сергей да как любая другая авторизация: туда некие реквизиты, оттуда "иди нафик" и закрытие соединения или "дратути, давайте ваши данные".

Comment: значит я правильно думал, вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/872442/python-%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80) продолжение моих изучений). После решение проблемы можно просто вместо "Hello" принмать пару логин/пароль? Ардуинка присылает шифрованные данные в байтах, там уже будет нужная инфа для идентификации, можно будет обойтись без таких запросов?

Comment: спасибо, xinetd стал полным решением проблемы, всё подошло как нельзя к стати! Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

есть такие вещи как SCADA система (то что у вас стоит на сервере и записывает и отображает данные, например [MasterSCADA](https://insat.ru/products/?category=9) - у них можно взять демку на 40 точек, а для платы можно взять [OPC-сервер](https://www.st4makers.com/download-opc-server-for-arduino), все это связать во едино, и в общем-то все готово! При возможности  вливания денег на проект и желании, проект можно расширять хоть до бесконечности. При этом вообще всю логику можно перенести непосредственно в SCADA. Вот вам собственно готовое решение по вашему вопросу. Ну и для объективности приведу еще несколько систем SCADA:

1. [simple-scada](https://simple-scada.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjwtvnbBRA5EiwAcRvnpsIp1x_6ckaU1Uo-AKbYY5sU2Fu3OZSLMi6Xlb6hmPjWFEWUBXGQdBoCCOcQAvD_BwE)
2. [rapidscada](https://rapidscada.ru/)
3. [simplight](https://simplight.ru/allproducts/simp-light-free)
4. [IGSS](http://igss.schneider-electric.com/products/igss/download/free-scada-ru.aspx)
5. [SoloScada light](http://opc-servers.ru/web-scada-soloscada/lite-)
6. [TRACE MODE](http://www.adastra.ru/products/dev/scada/)

Выбирайте, пробуйте пользуйтесь!